# add plugins to a go program

Tags: go, plugins

I need to provide pluggable functionality to a `Go` program.
The idea is that a 3rd party can add functionality for a given path, i.e.

`/alive` maps to `http://localhost:9876`, or
`/branding` maps to `http://localhost:9877` and so on.

I first tried to think of it as adding a `JSON` config file, where each such plugin would have an entry, e.g.:

```
{
  "Uri": "alive",
  "Address":"http://localhost:9876",
  "Handler":"github.com/user/repo/path/to/implementation"
},
```

This though blatantly reveals `Java` thinking - and feels like utterly inadequate for `Go` - there is no notion of Class loaders in `Go`, and loading this would mean to have to use the `loader` package from `golang`'s tools.

Proposals on how to do this in a more `Go`- idiosyncratic way? In the end I just need to be able to map a URI to a port and to an implementation.

Comment: Why do you need to map to a port and an implementation? If you're proxying requests, you need only the port, and if you're forwarding requests within the process, you don't need a port. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Adrian the project already has a webserver running, but due to its specific route handling can't be extended. Thus for some additional feature requests, the client says in his words: "...[a soluition] flexible enough that different people can have different alive / branded pages on their installation without needing to fork the complete codebase."

Comment: OK... if they're exposing a server on a port, then you don't need any kind of "plugin", just configuration mapping route -> port (like a proxy). If they're not exposing a port, but rather exposing a Go plugin (shared library), you don't need a port. A path to a package won't do you a lot of good unless you intend for your application to download and build it from source at runtime - a strange use case and one that requires the Go toolchain be installed in the deployed environment in production.

Comment: @Adrian many thanks - I think this comment helped me finally understanding way better what's actually being asked. I will need a "default" implementation - ours -, which will need to just check if someone has provided an external server/port for a specific route. If provided, proxy requests to that one, if not, use default implementation.

Comment: Then all you need is a config file that takes a URL to proxy to. No "plugin" necessary.

Comment: yep. that became my conclusion too. Thanks for facilitating me to get there.

Answer (score 3):

### Compile-time configuration

If you can live with compile-time configuration, then there is no need for a JSON (or any other) configuration file.

Your `main` package can import all the involved "plugins", and map their handler to the appropriate path. There is also no need to create multiple servers, although you may do so if that fits better your (or the modules') needs.

### Run-time configuration

Run-time configuration and plugging in a new module requires code to be loaded at run-time. This is supported by the [`plugin`](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/) package, but currently only under linux.

For this you may use a JSON config file, where you would list the compiled plugins (path to the compiled plugins) along with the paths you need to map them.

In the `main` package you can read the config file, and load the plugins, which should expose a variable or a function that returns you the handler that handles the traffic (requests). This is preferred to the plugins themselves firing up an http server for performance reasons, but both can work (plugins returning a handler for you to register, and the plugins launching their servers).

Note that there is also no need to make the configuration "static", the main app could receive and load new modules at runtime too (e.g. via a dedicated handler, which could receive the (file) path to the new module and the path to map it to, optionally maybe even the binary plugin code too; but don't forget about security!).

Note that while you can load plugins at runtime, there is no way to "unload" them. Once a plugin is loaded, it will stay in memory until the app exists.

### Separate, multi-apps

There is a third solution, in which your main app would act as a proxy. Here you may start the additional "modules" as separate apps, listening on localhost at specific ports, and the main app would act as a proxy, forwarding requests coming in to the other independent apps listening on different ports @localhost (or even on other hosts).

The standard library provides you the [`httputil.ReverseProxy`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy) doing just this.

This does not require runtime code loading, as the "modules" are separate apps which can be launched separately. Still, this gives runtime configuration flexibility, and this solution also works on all platforms. Moreover this setup supports taking down modules at runtime, as you can just as easily un-map / close the apps of the independent modules.

The separate apps can also be launched separately, or from / by the main app, both solutions are viable.

Comment: Thanks. At compile-time doesn't work for us - we don't know who can add plugins. In fact I proposed this JSON config because up to now cmd line params like `--http-handler /alive: localhost:9876` had been proposed - which I didn't like much as it makes the cmd line huge to start the program. I will explore "Run-time" and "multi-apps" as you suggest, looks good Thanks again!

Comment: Regarding command line params, while you may have moved away from it for this situation, it might be worth taking a look at [iniflag](https://github.com/vharitonsky/iniflags) for similar situations in the future.  It allows you to put all of those config flags into an ini file loaded at startup rather than supplying them on the command line (though you can also supply any of them on the command line, and flags supplied in the CLI override the same flag in the ini).